# How to simplify compound negated logic

Tags: c, if-statement, logic

Lets say I have array of boolean values B[], or I am figuring out true/false using function. How can I simplify this code, it there are many values (maybe tens of them)? Here is pseudocode:

```
if(!B[0]){
    doTask1;
}
if(!B[0] && !B[1]){
    doTask1;
    doTask2;
}
if(!B[0] && !B[1] && !B[2]){
    doTask1;
    doTask2;
    doTask3;
}
...
```

Edit 1: I forgot to mention, that I want doTask1 etc. happen only once (if any of there ifs is true), not doing it multiple times(if for example 1.st if is true, second one is true too, i still need to happen it only once)

Comment: So, `if B[0] == B[1] == B[2] ==  0`  you are doing `task1` three times. Do you want this?

Comment: Maybe you should try explaining the behavior you want w/o using code.

Comment: @RishikeshRaje Your are right, I want it to happen just one time. I will update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Assuming you *don't* want to make the same task more than once, even though your original code will)

Make a function `doTask()` which will take the number of the task to do (or just make an array of function pointers). And then:

```
for(i=0; i < numberOfTasks; i++)
{
     if (!B[i])
         doTask(i);
     else
         break;
}
```

Or more concisely:

```
for(i=0; i < numberOfTasks && !B[i]; i++)
{
     doTask(i);
}
```

Comment: That's what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

You can use array of function pointers.

```
typedef void *(* funcPtr)(void);

funcPtr arrayFunPtr[N];
```

Then store the functions into the array.

```
arrayFunPtr[0]= task1;
arrayFunPtr[1]= task2;
....
arrayFunPtr[N-1]= taskN;
```

Then loop the `bool` array and call respective index function.

```
  for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
  {
    if(!B[i]) arrayFunPtr[i]();
  }
```

---

***@Edit.***

If you want to stop calling `tasks` function once you hit `B[i]=true` use the below code.

```
  for(int i=0;i<N && !B[i] ;i++)
  {
      arrayFunPtr[i]();
  }
```

Comment: This is not equivalent. If I understand the requirement, you should do nothing after the first `B[i]` is true.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I don't know, as OP is not mentioned anything of that sort. Anyway I will update the answer.

Comment: The code he posted is showing exactly this. No task will be done if `B[0]` is true.

Comment: After update it meets all requirements, and it is working, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Function pointers is the way to go here.
If you do not like function pointer you might use the `switch` construct as shown below:

```
switch(i) {
    case 3:
       if(!B[0] && !B[1] && !B[2]) doTask3();
    case 2:
       if(!B[0] && !B[1]) doTask2();
    case 1:
       if(!B[0]) doTask1();
}
```

Or you can do :

You can write a method :

```
simplify(int[] B, int l) {
   for (int i =0 ; i < l, i++) {
       // write the code using &&
   }
}
```

Then can call this method as :

```
if(simplify(B, 1){
   doTask1;
}

if(simplify(B, 2){
   doTask1;
   doTask2;
}
```

etc.

Comment: Looks a little bit longer, if I have to write multiple ifs, but meets requirements and works!